# Change theme of website

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

i want to change color theme of my website on button click. Please give me any reference website url, from where i can have some idea.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538) and [Stack Overflow is not Twitter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131270/177538)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Google to find that information, but anyway...

On my website for themes I used PHP to store a cookie (e.g. $_COOKIE['themePref']) on the user's machine.
The cookie stores the name of the CSS file to be loaded for the user and is then echoed out in the head using PHP.

I found cookies to be the best way for this, because it means the user doesn't require an account (to store their preference in a database).